# Simultaneous send() and recv() between a server and client program in C?

Tags: sockets, tcp, send, tcpclient, recv

I'm doing a program where I have a client and server. What the client does is 'ping' the server by sending a msg that contains 'ping'. When the server gets the 'ping' it should send back a 'got_it'.

I'm already able to send the 'ping', it's already received by the server and send back a 'got_it' but my client couldn't receive it.

do I need to make two sockets to do this?
here's the code of my client.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  socklen_t len = sizeof(servaddr);
  char mesg[1024];
  char mesg2[1024];
  char cli_ip[32];

  if(argc!=2){ 
    printf("Usage: %s <ip_addr>\n",argv[0]);
    return -EINVAL; 
  }

  sockfd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(sockfd<0) {
    perror("socket: ");
    return -EIO;
  }

  bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(54321);
  inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&servaddr.sin_addr);

  if(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr))<0){
    perror("connect: ");
    close(sockfd);
    return -EIO;


  }

  while(1){
        memset(mesg2,0,sizeof(mesg2));
    if(recv(sockfd,mesg2,sizeof(mesg2),0) > 0 ){
        puts(mesg2);
    }
    fgets(mesg,sizeof(mesg),stdin);
    send(sockfd,mesg,strlen(mesg),0);



  }
  close(sockfd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the server is responding correctly?  Have you tested that it sends the "got_it" when you use other tools, e.g. telnet?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I'm pretty sure the server works. The client is the one having problems. When I run the client it gets stuck in the recv() part but when I remove the recv() function it runs smoothly.

Comment: Your client calls `recv()` before it ever calls `send()`! When does it ever send the "ping" message?

Comment: @j_random_hacker okay. so, I edited the code, I called send() before the recv(). It now receives the "got_it". yay! :D but if I send anything other than "ping" it gets stuck on the recv() part again. It seems that if it doesn't receive anything it just gets stuck there.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are expecting to happen -- waiting for a message is what recv() does!

Comment: @j_random_hacker ahh, I get it now. The recv waits for a mesg until it gets one but what I want is for it to just check for mesg. I've fixed it, I just needed to make the socket nonblocking.

Comment: Glad you fixed the immediate problem, but if you now have a non-blocking `recv()` call inside a `while` loop that does nothing else then you'll be using 100% CPU. If you really need the client to be doing something when there are no messages to process, it's much better to use a blocking `recv()` on a separate thread.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I need to stop waiting for replies after 2 sec. If the the `recv()` blocks it won't work. if I use 'fork()' how will I be able to say to the mother program that I've already received a reply?

Comment: Most blocking calls can be interrupted with `alarm()`, or provide some other way to set a timeout.